# onYouTubePlayerAPIReady fails to trigger under Opera

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Embedded Youtube video doesn't shows up on Opera.

Evidently callback is being defined later than YT api library is being loaded, but couldn't find any workaround.

Currently page is loading YT api via /player_api js inclusion and that works only on Firefox.

Tried to load YT api via

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
<script>
```

but in that case page is not working neither on Opera nor in Firefox.

page with problem is: 
http://www.ionpoverty.tv/blog/featured/having-it-all-low-income-women-and-work-inequality/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the way you're including the js is blocking the script below it from executing.  Each browser handles blocking scripts slightly differently, which is why you see it working in one and not the other.  Go ahead and move the script to load `www.youtube.com/iframe_api` to after where you define `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`.  I also recommend changing it to `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` but either should work.

The other thing you can do is make sure you load `www.youtube.com/iframe_api` and define 'onYouTubeIframeAPIReady' in the same script tag.  Because it is a single threaded environment this should ensure that onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is defined before the other script is included.

Comment: Greg, i did the change: and after moving youtube api inclusion line below onYouTubePlayerAPIReady video fails in Firefox too

Comment: oh sorry, actually it works and now in Opera too! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great.  If you could accept this as a correct answer that would be great.